# Nodejs, about npm install

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi All while installing the npm packages i am getting the following error in command prompt please provide solution because i am unable to resolve this error

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EACCES: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect EACCES 151.101.8.162:80
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js failed, reason: connect EACCES 151.101.8.162:80
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:385:9)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js failed, reason: connect EACCES 151.101.8.162:80
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:385:9)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR!   message: 'request to http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js failed, reason: connect EACCES 151.101.8.162:80',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   stack: 'FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js failed, reason: connect EACCES 151.101.8.162:80\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\pacote\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\node_modules\\node-fetch-npm\\src\\index.js:68:14)\n    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)\n    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:385:9)\n    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)',
npm ERR!   parent: 'test-app' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL-002\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-21T06_54_56_016Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: Read the error, "_Please try running this command again as root/Administrator_"

Comment: Please start command prompt  with administrator rights and then fire npm command.

Comment: Hi Milan , i have tried with administrator but still  i am getting the same error

Comment: Hi baj9032 i have already run the command prompt as administrator but still i am getting same error